# How to generate a list of lists using probabilities for each element in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I want to verify if i am doing things right, the question is :
The function random, without arguments, assumed to be imported, returns a random real of the interval [0,1[. Write a function init(N) taking as input a strictly positive integer, and returning a grid (NxN) (in the form of a list of lists), each cell containing a cell with a value of True with a probability of 1/3. For example:

init(4) => [[True, False, False, False],[False, False, True, True],[False,False,False,False],[True,False, True, False]]

```
from random import random
def init(N):
    return [ [True if random()<1/3 else False  for j in range(N)] for i in range (N) ]
print(init(4))
```

I am confused is the probablity 1/3 means that the generated random value is less than 1/3 or it is referring to a weighted probability such the one used in `random.choice`

Comment: From what I understand, both approaches are the same. You can either say that if the result of random is <1/2 then it is True, else it is False, and tweak the probabilities for the result to be <1/2 only 1/3 of the time OR say that the result will be distributed normally, but that True will be returned only if the result is <1/3.
The easy way is the second, and it is what's been done here, which works greatly btw!

Comment: Thank you, "You can either say that if the result of random is <1/2 then it is True, else it is False, and tweak the probabilities for the result to be <1/2 only 1/3 of the time". Can you explain more why should I consider 0.5 as a threshold.

Comment: `random()` returns a float in this interval [0;1). Thus, because you have two outcomes, you could consider the threshold to be 0.5 (but it would not **really** matter). The main point is that you could "weigh" the probabilities in order for the result to effectively be <0.5 (or the threshold you've determined) only 1/3 of the time. This would be way more complex than what you've done, and frankly I wouldn't know **why** someone would do that. To be more precise you chose a particular case, putting the threshold at 0.333, which allows you to not touch the underlying distribution.